# Using Swig to Wrap Fluent Interfaces

Tags: python, garbage-collection, swig, fluent, chaining

I'm using Swig to wrap a class implemented in C++. This class uses a fluent interface to allow method chaining. That is, methods that modify the state of an object return the reference to the object and, thus, allow to call the next state modifying method. For example:

```
class FluentClass {
public:
    ...
    FluentClass & add(std::string s)
    {
        state += s;
        return *this;
    }
    ...
private:
    std::string state;
};
```

The method `add` adds the given string `s` to `state` and returns the reference to the object allowing one to chain multiple calls of `add`:

```
FluentClass fc;
c.add(std::string("hello ")).add(std::string("world!"));
```

You will find more comprehensive examples at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface

I wrote several swing files (nothing special) to create bindings for multiple languages, in particular: C#, Java, Python, and Ruby. The following example (Python) works as expected:

```
fc = FluentClass()
fc.add("hello").add("world!")
```

However, the following does not:

```
fc = FluentClass()
fc = fc.add("hello").add("world!")
```

I found that calling `add` on `fc` does not return the reference of `fc` but a reference (I'm expecting that the other bindings will do the same) to a newly create object that actually wraps the same memory:

```
fc = FluentClass()
nfc = fc.add("hello world!")
fc != nfc, though fc and nfc wrap the same memory :(
```

Therefore, assigning the result of `add` to the same variable leads to the destruction of the original object as part of the garbage collection. The result is that `fc` now points to invalid memory.

So my question is: Do you know how to wrap `FluentClass` properly, to let `add` return the same reference in order to prevent garbage collection?

Comment: You have a memory ownership problem. (The call to constructor results in a proxy that "owns" the thing it points to, which gets destroyed when the new, non-owning proxy is created). I think there's a cute trick we can use to make this work much better, but I won't be able to validate it until later tonight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when the Python proxy created when you construct your instance gets destroyed the underlying C++ object gets deleted. Since SWIG doesn't know that the returned value is a reference to the same object it constructs a new proxy when you call `add`. As a result in the case you observed errors the original object has its ref count hit 0 before the chained methods are finished.

To investigate and fix first I created a test case to reproduce the issue properly. This was fluent.h:

```cpp
#include <string>

class FluentClass {
public:
    FluentClass & add(std::string s)
    {
        state += s;
        return *this;
    }
private:
    std::string state;
};
```

Enough code to reliably hit SEGFAULT/SIGABRT in testing in Python:

```py
import test

def test_fun():
    f=test.FluentClass()
    f=f.add("hello").add("world")

    return f

for i in range(1000):
    f2=test_fun()
    f2.add("moo")
```

And a SWIG interface file to build the module 'test':

```
%module test

%{
#include "fluent.h"
%}

%include <std_string.i>

%include "fluent.h"
```

With this extra work done I was able to reproduce the problem you reported. (Note: throughout this I'm targeting SWIG 3.0 with Python 3.4).

You need to write typemaps to handle the special case where 'returned value == this'. I initially wanted to target the argout typemap of the special 'this' argument as this felt like the right place to be doing this kind of work, but that also matches on the destructor call unfortunately which would have made writing the typemaps correctly harder than needed so I skipped that.

In my out typemap, which only gets applied to fluent types I check that we really do meet the "input is output" assumption and aren't simply returning something else. Then it bumps the reference count of the input so that I can safely return it with the semantics expected.

In order to make that work in the out typemap though we need to do a bit more work to safely and robustly capture the input Python object. The problem here is that SWIG generates the following function signature:

```
SWIGINTERN PyObject *_wrap_FluentClass_add(PyObject *SWIGUNUSEDPARM(self), PyObject *args) {
```

where the SWIGUNUSEDPARAM marco expands to simply not name the first parameter at all. (This looks like a bug to me in the macro definition, since it's the minor version of GCC that determines which option gets picked in C++ mode, but nonetheless we want it to work still).

So what I ended up doing was writing a custom in typemap that reliably captures the C++ this pointer and the Python object associated with it. (The way it's written works even if you enable one of the other argument unpacking styles and should be robust to other variations. It will however fail if you name other arguments 'self'). To put the values somewhere that can be used from the later 'out' typemap and don't have problems crossing goto statements we need to use the `_global_` prefix when [declaring local variables](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Typemaps.html#Typemaps_nn23).

Finally we need to do something sane in the non-fluent case. So the resulting file looks like:

```
%module test

%{
#include "fluent.h"
%}

%include <std_string.i>
%typemap(in) SWIGTYPE *self (PyObject *_global_self=0, $&1_type _global_in=0) %{
  $typemap(in, $1_type)
  _global_self = $input;
  _global_in = &$1;
%}

%typemap(out) FLUENT& %{
  if ($1 == *_global_in) {
    Py_INCREF(_global_self);
    $result = _global_self;
  }
  else {
    // Looks like it wasn't really fluent here!
    $result = SWIG_NewPointerObj($1, $descriptor, $owner);
  }
%}

%apply FLUENT& { FluentClass& };

%include "fluent.h"
```

Using `%apply` here makes the control of where this gets used simple and generic.

---

As an aside you can also tell SWIG that your `FluentClass::add` function consumes  its first argument and creates a new one, using:

```
%module test

%{
#include "fluent.h"
%}

%include <std_string.i>

%delobject FluentClass::add;
%newobject FluentClass::add;

%include "fluent.h"
```

Which generates more correct code in a much simpler way by decoupling the death of the first proxy from the real delete call. Equally though it's more verbose to have to write this for every method and it wouldn't be correct in all cases still, even though in my test case it is correct e.g.

```
f1=test.FluentClass()
f2=f.add("hello").add("world") # f2 is another proxy object, which now owns
f3=f1.add("again") # badness starts here, two proxies own it now....
```

Comment: Your solution looks good so far. However, do you really think we need to increment the ref count (Py_INCREF(_global_self);). I mean, we return the same instance ($result = _global_self;) and, thus, I expect `f2` to be equals to `f` (`f2` == `f`). I didn't test it yet, though.

Comment: In Python you now have two ways to refer to the same thing. So its ref count should be 2. I think I can demonstrate this more clearly so I'll write up a bit more detail on it over the weekend. (The short version is that the input arguments are only borrowed references). For comparison purposes even if you return the singleton global Py_True you still need to increment the ref count to be correct.

Answer (score -1):

The following code would work for ruby and python.

```
%{
typedef FluentClass FC_SELF;
%}

%typemap(out) FC_SELF& { $result = self; }

class FluentClass {
public:
  FC_SELF& add(const std::string& s);
};
```

"self" is the variable name of C pointer used in Ruby and Python C API to refer to a self object. So if the return type of a method is FC_SELF, the method will return the self object. The same trick would apply for other languages. But using a smart pointer is definitely a better solution, which will be in other answers.

Comment: Even if this typemap compiles (I can't test it yet, but expect it won't) it definitely won't get ref counting right in Python.

Comment: This doesn't compile with SWIG 3.0 targeting Python 3 - the definition of SWIGUNUSED is such that the ignored function argument doesn't actually have a name and can't be accessed. You'd also need a `Py_INCREF` to get the refcounting right I think and I wouldn't recommend using typedef like that. (`%apply` would be a better way to get the same result).